# IEnumerable<T>'requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, postsharp

In order to make changes in the dll given to us i used IAspectProvider interface and satisfy its required ProvideAspects method. as

```
public class TraceAspectProvider : IAspectProvider {
    readonly SomeTracingAspect aspectToApply = new SomeTracingAspect();

    public IEnumerable ProvideAspects(object targetElement) {
        Assembly assembly = (Assembly)targetElement;
        List instances = new List();
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
            ProcessType(type, instances);
        }
        return instances;
    }
    void ProcessType(Type type, List instances) {
        foreach (MethodInfo targetMethod in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)) {
            instances.Add(new AspectInstance(targetMethod, aspectToApply));
        }
        foreach (Type nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes()) {
            ProcessType(nestedType, instances);
        }
    }
}
```

while running this i am getting these error

waiting for your valuable comments

Comment: Please post the entire error/stacktrace if you want more detailed help.

Comment: i just copied the code from [link]http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/ [/link] i do not know where to change it can you guide me

Comment: Copying code without knowing what it does can be a very bad thing. I asked you to show the error, and you still haven't done that. Also `I have state that this functionality is undocumented because it isn’t officially supported by PostSharp. Proceed at your own risk.` is in the very first paragraph of that article.

Comment: Hmmm just now i started studying postsharp is it possible to provide static aspect weaver using postsharp to dll file and compile it.can you guide me that how to proceed with that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `ProvideAspects()`](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/M_PostSharp_Aspects_IAspectProvider_ProvideAspects.htm), you will notice that it returns `IEnumerable<AspectInstance>`, so that's what you have to use in your code too:

```
public class TraceAspectProvider : IAspectProvider {
    readonly SomeTracingAspect aspectToApply = new SomeTracingAspect();

    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement) {
        Assembly assembly = (Assembly)targetElement;
        List<AspectInstance> instances = new List<AspectInstance>();
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
            ProcessType(type, instances);
        }
        return instances;
    }
    void ProcessType(Type type, List<AspectInstance> instances) {
        foreach (MethodInfo targetMethod in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)) {
            instances.Add(new AspectInstance(targetMethod, aspectToApply));
        }
        foreach (Type nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes()) {
            ProcessType(nestedType, instances);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya Thanks for your help it executed well

Comment: Have you ever worked on postsharp just now i am started researching on it.... is it possible to provide static aspect weaver using postsharp to dll file and compile it

Comment: @Gowthammanju I have never worked with it. And you shouldn't ask unrelated questions in comments, create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` and `List<someClass>` for this.
Also check out `yield return` specifically made to be used in such situation.

Comment: i just copied the code from [link]http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/[/link]  i do not know where to change it can you guide me

Comment: @Gowthammanju The blog software probably ate the pieces of code inside `<>`.

Comment: @Gowthammanju That is my blog post and yes, wordpress killed the <>. It should be a generic of type AspectInstance. List<AspectInstance>